# Category Filter in add product option when creating order from backend

Tags: category-products, order-grid

When i am creating an order from backend and clicking on add a product option its showing me all products and showing fields of id, product name, sku, price, select, qty to add ... what i want to do is to add a field and drop down filter for category so that i can easily get products from a particular category and will save time in selecting my required product to add in order ... i found the block file from where these fields are called Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Create_Search_Grid ..... can anbody please give me solution for this

below is screenshot for order add product option where i want to add category

[image]

Comment: Also just looking for the same thing too.